# Error <Class> has not attribute <method> in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to link  a tkinter frame to another one, but I get this error

> AttributeError: 'mainscreen' object has no attribute 'nextscreen'

my code is below :

What is the meaning of this error?

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import imap
class mainscreen():
    def __init__(self,tkgui):
        global w,x
        self.tkgui =tkgui
        tkgui.configure(background='red')
        Label(tkgui,text='please Enter your email',bg='red',fg='white').grid(row=0,column=2)
        e=Entry(tkgui,width=20)
        e.grid(row=1,column=2)
        w=e.get()
        print(w)
        Label(tkgui,text='please Enter your Password',bg='red',fg='white').grid(row=2,column=2)
        p=Entry(tkgui,width=20,show='*')
        p.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=w)
        x=p.get()
        Button(tkgui,text="Sign ON").grid(row=5,column=2)
        Button.bind('<button>',self.nextscreen())
    def nexscreen(self,event):
        inboxscreen=imap.signin(w,x)
tkgui=tkinter.Tk()
app=mainscreen(tkgui)
tkgui.mainloop()
```

Comment: The meaning is exactly what it says: you are trying to access an attribute named `nextscreen` from an object named `mainscreen`, but that object has no attribute with that name.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you have a typo. In your code, the function is named `nexscreen` but you call it with `nextscreen`

Comment: Thanks my bad it was actually typo error but still I cant convert the p,get() into str so I can pass the parameters to the imap in the second code

Comment: Best to post that as a separate question, I'd say.